# Implications of lots of non-permitted work in a house purchase/sale

Tags: inspection, permitting

Looking at houses, we have found one that has been completely redone (footings to rafters in many places) but without permits for the most part. The original house was from 1908, it was redone and added onto in the 1970s, and the current owner redid nearly everything in the 2000s-2010s. I know the owner so I'm not personally worried about the work (he also had plumbers/electricians out for work outside his expertise).

We really would like the house, but I'm worried about the future implications of trying to sell a house with lots of un-permitted work. Has anyone had experience with this type of situation? Here are some sub-questions related to things I'm most concerned about, but any related experience is welcome.

1. Are there any legal implications with a lot of un-permitted work on a home?
2. If I want to ger a permit for work *I* want to do on the home, will there be complications?

Comment: You need to contact a lawyer/conveyancing expert. Some of the early work may by now be grandfathered/legacy. Some may or may not have needed prior/post approval at the time. I have a house extension done without any approval at all 'long ago' that has now achieved 'legacy' status, but it cannot be touched again without full planning permission.

Comment: See also https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/89654/implications-of-lots-of-non-permitted-work-in-a-house-purchase-sale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, unless the building is brand new construction, it is extremely unlikely that there won't be some kind of unpermitted work that has been done on it.

Judge the building by the quality and condition of the work.  I have a fair amount of extremely shoddy electrical work that was very likely original to the house, permitted and signed off.  I also hae lots of very good electrical work that I did myself, mostly without permits and inspections.  That there was a permit or not doesn't matter much when purchasing/selling a home.  I am on my third home/fourth mortgage and I have never once had a lender or insurer ask if permits were pulled for any work.  The inspection is what counts.

Have the building properly inspected.  If an inspection reveals something that is against code or unsafe, it should be fixed regardless of whether it was done by the original builder 50 years ago, or Joe the handyman last summer.  By the same token, if the work was obviously done correctly, then it doesn't matter now whether someone pulled a permit back then or not.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. "The inspection is what counts" makes a lot of sense to me. I think that is a great next step, and probably will make things clearer anyways. Good to hear the "permitting" part may play less of a role in an actual buy/sell situation.

Comment: This would depend on local law. In my state, ALL known unpermitted/uninspected work on the house must be fully disclosed at sale, since it constites a known "defect". Not doing so is grounds for new owner to recover full cost of rework/permitting/inspection with possibly additional liability for punitive damages as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you really like it, I wouldn't let this stop you from buying it.  But,  you need to make sure the seller gets all the issues addressed first. It is really the seller's problem to fix and not yours.  I would hire a lawyer to draft a offer that is very specific with the issues to be addressed.

Comment: *It is really the seller's problem to fix and not yours.* Actually, it isn't. The buyer can put in contingencies to require the seller to fix it, to require the seller to pay for it (i.e., lower the sale price or have some money change hands at closing to cover estimated repair costs) or buy it "as is". If it is a "seller's market" then if the buyer makes the seller fix/pay then the seller may say "forget it, I'll find another buyer".

Comment: Yes, those things can be done, but why would he want to make the seller's problem, his problem?  He can make a (likely) bad decision and buy it "as is" but why do that? The offer should include a contingency for the seller to clean up the unpermitted issue.  If the Seller is not willing to do that, either walk away or take your chances.  It'd be worth talking to your title company too; they may be able to provide special coverage for this situation.

Comment: In a really hot market, the offer with no contingencies wins. In a normal market these are reasonable points for negotiation.

Comment: The only things that need to be fixed after an inspection are those agreed to by both parties.  If the seller says, "nah," you're generally free to accept the non-repair or walk (or you negotiate a discount).  Whether the work is permitted or unpermitted usually depends on the locality.  In most cases the home inspector won't know if the work is permitted—they don't generally pull homes' records from the permitting dept.  The only thing they'll know (and even only sometimes, at that) is whether it's code-compliant or safe.

Comment: What the OP _should do_ in this situation is entirely opinion based. Some of our commenters here hold the opinion that the OP "should" make the seller fix everything, others are of the opinion that the OP _could_ buy it as is. This is why opinion-based questions are off-topic...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a very common situation. Basically if you buy the house it’s your problem but it may never become a problem. I’ve bought two places with lots of unpermitted work and no real problems yet.

Surely do an inspection to see what is an issue. The inspector won’t tell you anything about what was permitted or not but rather what is not up to code. If it’s serious, don’t buy the place or have the seller fix it first.

If you do buy the place it could become an issue if you do further work that you want inspected, that could lead to the inspector discovering prior work that they want signed off on. Like the other commenter said, that might require ripping open a wall so electrical or plumbing could be inspected. Not the end of the world but not pleasurable.

As to whether a future buyer would be turned off, maybe but I doubt it. You’re a prospective buyer right now and you’re thinking about it. Just becomes one more factor, in addition to cost, location, market conditions, etc. In demanding markets sellers can often unload a house with no inspections just because demand is so high. You’ll have to decide if you think that’s the future of your location.